# Will my spouse divorce me if I ignore them or pursue others?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm trying to figure out how marriage works. Wiki says I can either talk to my wife/husband and it will gradually make them happier up to a certain threshold, but it doesn't say much about ignoring them. The only info it has is they may say rude things, but that's about it.

It's currently winter and so I can't marry anyone yet (because a certain NPC required for this does not appear in winter, apparently), so I'd like to prepare while there's still time. I've adopted a cat earlier and all it does is block my way to item storage during rainy days when it teleports inside the house, making me wish I could disown it. And I "touch" it every day and get "love" in response. I'd like to know what my spouse would try to pull if I ignore them or gave gifts to other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no divorce option in the game as of yet, but it's being considered for the next update.

Friendship with your spouse works largely the same as friendship with any other NPC, with two more additions: if you gift an item to another bachelor/ette, your spouse will get upset and lose some friendship, letting you know that they saw you "secretly giving a gift" to someone else; similarly, declaring your love to someone with a Bouquet will lower friendship by a bigger amount (~2 hearts).